# Convergence almost surely and sum

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

There is a small thing I'm not understand. I have X1, ... , Xn random variables with:

$ \mid Xn \mid = 1/n$

I don't understand why:

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor1/\epsilon\rfloor} P(\mid Xn \mid > \epsilon) = \lfloor1/\epsilon\rfloor$

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor1/\epsilon\rfloor} P(\mid Xn \mid > \epsilon) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor1/\epsilon\rfloor} P(\frac{1}{n} > \epsilon)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor1/\epsilon\rfloor} 1\\
&={\lfloor1/\epsilon\rfloor}
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm really not understanding why P(1/n > e) = 1. Especially why 1 - P(1/n <= e) = 1. It means that P(1/n <= e) = 0 but why ? I know it's obvious but I cannot figure it out

Comment: Consider some $\epsilon > 0$. For the purpose of intuition, you can consider it to be some small real number (though the method works even otherwise). 

Then $\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon}\rfloor = N$ for some large N. Now for all $n\leq N$, $n<\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon}\rfloor < \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Therefore, $\forall n\leq N$, $\epsilon<\frac{1}{n}$. 

Thus $\forall n\leq \lfloor\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rfloor$, $\mathbb{P}[\epsilon<\frac{1}{n}] = 1$

Comment: Omg thank you ! I didn't take in account that n is changing based on the sum. It's not "for every n". Thank you very much !